# The %s format specifier with an unsigned char bigger than 127 in C

Tags: c

I wrote the following example programs but their outputs were not what I expected.
In my first program, `s` contains some characters but one of them is bigger than 127(`0xe1`). When I print `s` the output is not what I expected.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, len;

    unsigned char s[] = {0x74, 0x61, 0x6f, 0x62, 0xe1, 0x6f, 0x63, 0x64, 0x6e};

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(s) / sizeof(unsigned char); i++) {
        printf("%c ", s[i]);
    }

    printf("\n%s\n", s);                                                                                                               
    return 0;
}
```

Guess what? the outputs were:

```
t a o b c d n 
taobn@
```

Then I did some minor changes to the first program and here is my second program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, len;

    unsigned char s[] = {0x74, 0x61, 0x6f, 0x62, 0xe1, 0x6f, 0x63, 0x64, 0x6e};
    // Iteratively output was deleted here

    printf("%s\n", s);                                                                                                               
    return 0;
}
```

The outputs also astonished me, they were:

```
taobn
```

To checkout if this is a strange feature of `glibc`,  I wrote the third program which bypasses `glibc`'s I/O buffer and writes `s` directly into file with `write` system call.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{  
   int fd;                                                  
   unsigned char s[] = {0x74, 0x61, 0x6f, 0x62, 0xe1, 0x6f, 0x63, 0x64, 0x6e};

   if((fd = open("./a.out", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT)) < 0) {
        printf("error open\n");
        return -1;
    }

    write(fd, s, sizeof(s));
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

The outputs were still:

```
[cobblau@baba test]$ cat a.out
taobn
```

Can anyone explain this?  What's going on here?
Thanks.

Comment: the 's' array needs to be null terminated to use as you are in the printf() call.  Also, it is probable that your console driver, with its' currently selected codepage value, sees 0xe1 as part of a multi byte character.

Comment: Your command `cat a.out` doesn't execute the program but prints its content.

Answer (score 7):

Calling `printf("\n%s\n", s)` with variable `s` not pointing to a null-terminated string yields undefined behavior. In simple words, the last character in your array should be 0 (a.k.a. `\0`).

`%s` tells `printf` to print the characters located at the memory address pointed by the input argument, until a 0 character is encountered.

You are passing an array of characters which does not contain a 0 character, and so `printf` will continue reading characters from memory until it encounters 0 or performs an illegal memory access.

---

**Here is a how you could end up printing `"taobn@"`:**

Your array of characters is:

```
unsigned char s[] = {0x74, 0x61, 0x6f, 0x62, 0xe1, 0x6f, 0x63, 0x64, 0x6e};
```

Suppose that the characters located immediately after this array in memory are:

```
0x08, 0x08, 0x08, 0x08, 0x08, 0x6e, 0x40, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x08, 0x08, 0x08, 0x00
```

So in essence, `printf` will attempt to print the following null-terminated string:

```
unsigned char s[] = {0x74, 0x61, 0x6f, 0x62, 0xe1, 0x6f, 0x63, 0x64, 0x6e,
                     0x08, 0x08, 0x08, 0x08, 0x08, 0x6e, 0x40, 0x20, 0x20,
                     0x20, 0x08, 0x08, 0x08, 0x00};
```

Now, try to call `printf("%s",s)` and see what you get...

Comment: That's correct. But the char string contains the `0xE1 0x6F` before the 0x63. The last (0x63) yields a 'c' when you send it as individual chars but is dropped when it is send as string. This should not be dependent on a terminating zero.

Comment: Er... the null-terminated may not be the point. Actually, if I change the `s` definition to `unsigned char s[] = {0x74, 0x61, 0x6f, 0x62, 0xe1, 0x6f, 0x63, 0x64, 0x6e, '\0'}` and then call `printf("%s\n", s)`, the outputs is still `taobn`.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the problem that your string in currently not null terminated (which can lead to undefined behaviout) as others noted, the output of characters having code above 127 depends on current console charset.

You can have Single Byte Character Set like ISO-8859-1 (AKA Latin1), or its slight variation Windows 1252, CP850 or CP437, each with its own representation for high characters but where one byte is one character on one side, and Multi Byte Character Set like UTF8 on the other side.

As an example the string `éè` is represented by `{ 0xe9, 0xe8, 0 }` in ISO-8859-1, `{ 0x82, 0x8a, 0 }` in CP850 and `{ 0xc3, 0xa9, 0xc3, 0xa8, 0 }` in UTF8

Currently, when you try to print a character whose code in unknown in the console, you can get a `?`, a square or nothing depending on the system.

Comment: That's the point. BTW, could you tell me how to finger out which console charset my computer using and what's the meaning of each character under this charset?

Comment: It's heavily system and config dependant ... I'd try `chcp` on a Windows `cmd`, `echo $LANG` under Unix-like, or ask sysadmin

Answer (score 1):

Printing individual characters is different from printing a char array which **doesn't terminate with a null terminator**

```
unsigned char s[] = { 0x74, 0x61, 0x6f, 0x62, 0xe1, 0x6f, 0x63, 0x64, 0x6e };
printf("\n%s\n", s); // Wrong, undefined behavior
```

Alternatively you could provide the size yourself

```
printf("\n%.*s\n", (int)sizeof(s), s);
```

From [printf()'s documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/):

> .number
>
> For s: this is the maximum number of characters to be printed. By default all characters are printed until the ending null character is encountered.